# IMAP SEARCH for non-existing header

Tags: email, search, imap

How can I search for emails that's not a reply? I mean just the original email if it was a thread already. I tried looking for emails that has empty `In-Reply-To` header like:

```
? SEARCH HEADER In-Reply-To ""
```

But still returns emails that are replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That search returns messages whose In-Reply-To field contain the substring "", not ones that equal "".

What you want is something closer to `NOT HEADER In-Reply-To "@"`, which is a hack but not a bad one. If there is a valid, meaningful in-reply-to field in a message, then it contains `@`. If there is an In-Reply-To field that doesn't contain `@`, then IMO that's not worth basing any decision on. Maybe it's this aberration:

```
In-Reply-To: N/A
```